# Macros for asp.net debugging?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, macros

Is there a way to run browser macros when I start debugging asp.net project.?

I know you can specify start page in Proprties->Web, but can I do something more powerful, e.g.

1. Go to example.com/login
2. Type Login and Password
3. Click submit
4. Go to example.com/PageImDebugging

Comment: Googling for "test automation visual studio 2012" will give you a plethora of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks! I was googling for something like "web macros" which didnt produce anything useful.